# Assoc array to object no longer fails on false

Tags: php, mysqli, conditional-statements

I wrote some code to pull data from a database, and then return the results as an associative array, however I switched the return value to an object (which works), but it is no longer failing at the following condition when no results exist.

```
if($myobject = MyClass::GetRecords("something")) {
   // this code is now executing all the time
} else {
   // this code no longer executes even when there are no results
}


class MyClass {

    public static function GetRecords($myparam) {
        $cn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        $records = Array();
        $query = '
                    SELECT 
                        `' . DB_PREF . 'mytable`.`id`,
                        `' . DB_PREF . 'mytable`.`foo`,
                        `' . DB_PREF . 'mytable`.`bar`
                    FROM
                        `' . DB_PREF . 'mytable`
                    WHERE
                        `' . DB_PREF . 'mytable`.`bar`=?
                ';

        if ($s = $cn->prepare($query)) {
            $s->bind_param('s', $myparam);
            $s->execute();
            $result = $s->get_result();
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $records[] = $row;
            }

            switch(count($records)) {
                case 0:
                    $records = false;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $records = $records[0];
                    break;
            }

            $s->close();
        } else {
            // echo $cn->error;
        }

        mysqli_close($cn);
        return (object)$records;
    }

}
```

The condition works perfectly if I do `return $records;` instead of `return (object)$records;`

Why is this condition failing or what should i set `$records` to in order to ensure that condition fails when I want it to fail (eg, no records returned from database).  Presently, I set `$records` to `false` as this is defacto standard for failing a condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“Why is this condition failing”_ – simply because objects are always considered boolean “true”, even when they are “empty”.

Comment: @CBroe - how should I set the object to fail -- and check ?    `$records = empty()`  +  `if(!empty($records = MyClass::GetRecords('something'))`  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as mentioned in the comments, an object is considered true even when empty.

As an alternative just add some logic:

```
if (!$records){
    return false;
} else{
    return (object)$records;
}
```

Comment: was thinking of using something similar to this in the class.  this works tho.  ty